# Why my cat's(animal) mesh looks weird when posing? ;-;

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, blender

I'm making small "Game" in Unity3d Where i want to include animals like cat, dog, hamster or something like that. i need rigged models, so i started rigging in Blender ... then i met little obstacle on my way.

when i try to pose cat's legs it look in blender ... strange, in unity even more strange ;-;

i'm not much experienced in animation/rigging bcs i prefer to write scripts rather than modelling. Any ideas how to fix this?

i tried moving bones in various ways, adding some new bones, but nothing helped ... maybe(for sure) i've done something wrong ?

Edit: Same weird thing happens with front legs :/

[image] - Unity

[image] - Blender Mesh

[image] - Blender Rig

[image] - Blender Pose

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [ask], [tour] and [mcve]

Comment: nope, i've read this long time ago, i just posted it and you wrote comment when i was editing it ;d

Comment: Sounds like you have a rigging issue with your model.

Answer (score 0):

[Weight painting](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/painting/weight_paint/introduction.html) is the technique used to specify which vertices of your model are moved by each bone.

In your cat model, you have vertices in front of the leg that are configured to move with one of the leg bones. You need to remove or reduce the amount of movement for the leg bones in the area that is deforming badly.

Comment: thank you for this link ... i'll read more about that and try to figure something out. ^-^